# URL containing '?' causes error

Tags: hyperref, url

I'm using TeXmaker for OS X with `pdflatex` extension (I'm new to LaTeX, too), I've a problem with the `hyperref` package. I can't put `https://`, and special char like `?`. My document class is `report`.

Here is how I use the command:

```
\url{www.orange-sans-guigne.com/osg-forum/viewtopic.php?id=379}
```

And I get

```
www.orange-sans-guigne.com/osg-forum/viewtopic.php\protect\relax?id=379
```

When I add  `https://`

I get:

```
https\protect\relax:\@beginparpenalty=\@M\relax//www.orange-sans-guigne. com/osg-forum/viewtopic.php\protect\relax?id=379
```

I tried to use `url` package, but I get an error because I use `hyperref`.

**Solution**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{french} % This is why I got my url broken
\usepackage[french]{babel} % This is the solution
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\url{www.orange-sans-guigne.com/osg-forum/viewtopic.php?id=379}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for me (pdfLaTeX with vim/emacs, no nonsense, TeX Live 2016), looks like texmaker is escaping too much. `\documentclass{report} \usepackage[pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref} \usepackage{url} \begin{document} \url{www.orange-sans-guigne.com/osg-forum/viewtopic.php?id=379} \end{document}` [![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsYo9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsYo9.png)

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) Please provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet, that makes it a lot easier for others to test your code

Comment: The problem come from \usepackage{french}

Comment: Please, edit your question rather than using comments or the space for answers. Since the `french` package is not commonly used, a minimal example of code is really necessary.

Comment: @mytDRAGON: Please add a full compilable, but minimal example document (MWE). Consider asking "How to get ? into urls with french package" or similar. You current self-answer doesn't solve the issue. Therefore the whole question and answer is not very useful for others with the same problem.

Comment: I edited, sorry I'm new on this forum :c

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{french} % This is why I got my url broken
\usepackage[french]{babel} % This is the solution
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\url{www.orange-sans-guigne.com/osg-forum/viewtopic.php?id=379}

\end{document}
```

The problem is due to the package `\usepackage{french}`

Comment: and the solution is to use `\usepackage[french]{babel}` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it by removing the package but it is working with `{babel}`.

Answer (score 0):

As a member of the `french` package (`e-french` in the distributions) maintenance team, with Raymond Juillerat, I'm discovering your problem. At the moment, we don't have a real solution, but only a workaround:

```
\nonfrench\url{www.orange-sans-guigne.com/osg-forum/viewtopic.php?id=379}\endnonfrench
```

I must concede it is not very satisfying, but easy to insert in a `\newcommand` macro, and I believe that the `french` package has some qualities for typesetting texts in French.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries it seems that putting `\usepackage{french}` (or `\usepackage{efrench}`, it's the same) **after** `\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,plainpages=false]{hyperref}`
could solve the problem. The simplest idea is sometimes the more efficient.

Comment: Wouldn't an even better solution consist of not loading the `french` package in the first place? Instead, isn't it ok to load the `babel` package with the language option `french`: `\usepackage[french]{babel}`?

Comment: Well, the french package has some features absent from babel, it is more convenient, and more beautiful IMHO (I'm biased, of course, as a moral heir of the late Bernard Gaulle).

Comment: That's interesting. Is there a website somewhere that compares the advantages (and disadvantages, presumably) of the `french` and `babel` packages?

Comment: Hum, the best available is here: http://efrench.org/doc/, but not really a  comparison.